# Error handling stop propagation after router.navigate Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've implemented error handling on server side to return json. And now I'm working on error handling in Angular 2.

My component is:

```
onClick() {
        this.dataService.getData()
            .subscribe((response: Json) => {
                console.log("some text");
                if(response.status !== 'fail') {
                    ...
                }
            });
    }
```

My **DataService.ts** is:

```
getData(): Observable<Json> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.getDataUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return this.responseService.extractJson(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return this.errorService.handleError(error);
            });
    }
```

And **ResponseService.ts**:

```
extractJson(response: Response): any {
        let json: Json = response.json();
        if (json.status === 'success') {
            return json;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['something-went-wrong']);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But app continues to execute code further in *subscribe* section, so I see in browser console `some text` and error `Cannot read property 'status' of null`. How can I stop further propagation after `router.navigate`? What should I do or return after `router.navigate` for that?

Comment: Can you give more detail? What gets executed after the navigation?

Comment: can you make plnkr?

Comment: @echonax code in subscribe block in component gets executed after the navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return `null` in `extractJson` therefore you can just

```
onClick() {
    this.dataService.getData()
        .subscribe((response: Json) => {
            console.log("some text");
            if(!response) {
              // do nothing or whatever
              return
            }
            if(response.status !== 'fail') {
                ...
            }
        });
}
```

**update**
Use filter to prevent the `null` to be event emitted as an event:

```
getData(): Observable<Json> {
    return this.http
        .get(this.getDataUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return this.responseService.extractJson(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return this.errorService.handleError(error);
        }).filter(val => val != null);
}
```

Comment: Can I stop propagation straight in response.service?